# How to remove certain characters from cell on Excel

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am new to python and I am trying to run a program that runs down a list of values on Excel, and removes the "^" character from every index. For example, if i have a column that has the following values (MS144573^, MS655072^, MS655282^, MS655177^, MS655073^) I would like each value to be replaced to (MS144573, MS655072, MS655282, MS655177, MS655073).

I am using the Openpyxl module.

I cannot identify whether cells in Excel are strings, are characters. Any ideas?

i have tried the following code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook
path = "C:/Users/x/Desktop/x/x.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet_read = wb.get_sheet_by_name("report")
sheet_write = wb.active


for i in range(1, 10):
 x = sheet_write.cell(row = i, column = 1).value
 y = len(x)
 if x[y] == '^':
    x = x[:y-1]
```

But i get this error:

^ y = len(x)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Comment: So you want to remove the caret or the apostrophe? the substitute function in excel will do this.

Comment: Do you want to remove the `\`` character, or `^`? Your text and examples don't match.

Comment: @SolarMike @BruceWayne I want to remove the ` character. Please take a look at code.

Comment: @mali30 I read the text of your question - so get it together and explain what you mean clearly.

Comment: @SolarMike Let me reiterate. I have a column of values on my Excel Sheet that have this character ` at the end of every value. I am trying to write a script that removes the ` character.

Comment: @mali30 don’t reiterate - edit your original question so it is correct and clear. Posting clarifications in comments is poor form - why do you expect people to trawl through comments piecing together your question like it is a puzzle?

Comment: @solarmike I just realized that my example had "^" and ive been asking for "`". Thanks for pointing it out. Its been a long day...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the re module.

```
import re

value = re.sub('^', '', input)   # where input is the values that you want substituted
```

This would replace all instances of `^` with nothing, effectively removing it, and storing it in value. If you have more than one to do you can iterate through the list and simply append them to a new list of *cleaned* values.

EDIT: If you need more info on how to do this leave a comment and ill update the code to reflect your question.